# Problem on inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Prove that, $E|X|^p < \infty $ iff $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{p-1}P\{|X| \geq k\} < \infty$.
Where E is the expectation and P is the usual probability measure. There was a mistake one it's correct.

Comment: Hi. Your p value is greater than 1 or any real number?

Comment: Hi. Just to have a check if the power p is greater than 1?

Comment: p could be less than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_k:=\{\omega,k\leqslant |X(\omega)|\lt k+1\}$. Then switching the order or summation (allowed, as the series converge), we have that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{p-1}\mathbb P\{|X|\geqslant k\}<\infty\Leftrightarrow\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{p-1}\sum_{j\geqslant k}\mu(A_j)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mu(A_j)\sum_{k=1}^jk^{p-1}<\infty.$$
Since $\sum_{k=1}^jk^{p-1}\sim j^p$, the problem reduces to show that 
$$\mathbb E|X|^p\lt\infty\Leftrightarrow\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mu(A_j)j^p\lt\infty.$$
To see this, notice that 
$$j^p\chi_{A_j}\leqslant |X|^p\chi_{A_j}\leqslant (j+1)^p\chi_{A_j},$$
and $\bigcup_jA_j=\Omega$.